# Using multiple field query mongo perl

Tags: perl, mongodb

I have my between date queries working great, but am trying to add another and to this and failing.  Any ideas?

```
my $cursor = $collection
->find( { create_date => {'$gte' => $past,'$lt' => $present, status => $eq' => "F" }
#status => {
#'$eq' => "F'
#} } );
```

Comment: Didn't you see anything wrong with your post after you submitted it? I've tried to fix it but I can't be sure what you mean. Indent code by four spaces for highlighting

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a bracket:

```
my $cursor = $collection ->find( { create_date => {'$gte' => $past,'$lt' => $present}, status => {'$eq' => "F" }} )
```